# How to query SharePoint sites in a multi-geo SharePoint from a specific geo using Beta Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, beta

The Beta Microsoft Graph API supports multi-geo SharePoint (v1.0 non-beta does not support multi-geo).  However, I am having trouble using it to query the SharePoint sites in a specific geo using the C# beta SDK (latest version) from nuget.

Does anyone know how to query either all geos, or only a specific geo?  Right now, we have 3 geos and the API is only returning the US region geo sites, but not the others.

Comment: Can [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request) help you?

Comment: @TinyWang Thanks for the reply.  I actually tried this.  For the 2nd one there, it only enumerates in one geo.  For the first one, it only enumerates the top level sites but in all geos; however, the Sites property is null and I was not able to enumerate subsites for each of these top level / root sites.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but there is a new endpoint introduced this year which discovers [all root sites across all geographies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getallsites?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
GET /sites/getAllSites
```

It works only with the application permission `Sites.Read.All`. Supports all OData query parameters like `$select`, `$filter`, `$orderby`, `$top`, and `$count` except `$expand`.

If you need to then enumerate subsites. Use site id returned by the query above.

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/sites
```